# initialize turtles from the same patch for two different scenario runs

Tags: gis, netlogo

I want to run my NetLogo model to see how the change in landscape scenario 'baseline' and 'future' affects agents' annual travel distance.  I have initialized agents on a random patch within their residential postcode boundary.

To be able to compare changes in travel, I should have them initialized from the same patch for both scenarios. I have been trying using random-seed but can't get it to work. I want to run the model for 100 different initial patches but maintain the same patch for each baseline and future scenario in a single run (ideally that is two runs, one with baseline scenario and one future scenario.
When I use random-seed in setup, it initializes agents from different patches for each scenario.
I tried setting a global variable random-seed-turtles  and tried 2 runs in behaviour space with two different seeds.

```
[ "random-seed-turtles"  1 2 ]   
[  "landscape-scenario"   "baseline" "future"]
```

It creates turtles from the same patch for each run for baseline but differs for future scenario.

[image]

Is there a way to code so that I can have a different initial patch for turtles for each of the 100 runs but same origin for individual runs.
e.g.

```
run1 
baseline my_home  = patch 113 224
future  my_home  = patch 113 224
```

Also, does the place where you insert the random-seed command matter?
The patch value (landscape availability) changes every tick, reading from a raster prepared for that timestep. Landscape_scenario is a chooser on the interface with the values for 'baseline' and 'future' each reading a different set of rasters. Does this interfere random-seed?

Comment: Hi Vidushi, it is not easy to understand exactly the situation so it would be ideal to see some of your code (not all of it because I imagine that would be quite long, but a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).
Anyway, I need to know if I understood correctly... are both the *baseline* and *future* scenarios simulated as part of the same NetLogo run? i.e. If you click once your go-forever button, does that generate both a *baseline* simulation and a *future* simulation?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: The answer below assumes that your situation is such that you want the *baseline* and the *future* scenarios to be run as part of a single model iteration.

Also, I propose two (very similar) approaches. The one you'll prefer will depend on your specific situation and needs, that we don't know since you didn't share the structure of your model.

---

You have to create a turtles-own variable where each turtle will directly store its starting patch.

Then, when you close your *baseline* scenario and prepare your *future* scenario, you will have to manually delete all the variables that you want to delete **except** that variable where turtles stored their starting patch (so, for example, you shouldn't use `clear-all` or `clear-turtles` in that passage, because such commands would also clear the turtles-own variable that you want to keep).

To show the approach with an example, see the code below:

```
globals [
 ; Put here your gobal variables.
]

patches-own [
 ; Put here your patches' variables.
]

turtles-own [
 my-start
 my-value  ; I only included this to show that you have to manually clear the turtles' variables EXCEPT from 'my-start'.
]


to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  
  ; Do here what you need to do to prepare the baseline scenario.

  create-turtles 20 [
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   set my-value random 10
   set my-start patch-here
  ]
end


to go
  run-model
  
  clear-baseline-scenario
  prepare-future-scenario
  
  run-model
end


to run-model
  ; Put here all the things you need to have to run your model,
  ; including a stop condition (and ticks, if you want them).
end


to clear-baseline-scenario
  clear-globals
  clear-patches
  reset-ticks
  
  ; Now, you also have to manually clear all your turtles' variables EXCEPT
  ; from 'my-start':
  ask turtles [
   set my-value 0 
  ]
end


to prepare-future-scenario
  ; Do here what you need to do to prepare the future scenario,
  ; and also tell your agents to go to their starting patch:
  
  ask turtles [
   move-to my-start 
  ]
end
```

---

There is another approach which basically is just the same solution but applied to patches instead of turtles.

In this case, you will have a patches-own variable that signals if a patch is or isn't a starting patch (for example by taking 1/0 value, or `TRUE`/`FALSE` if you prefer).

Then, when going from the *baseline* scenario to the *future* scenario, you will clear all the things you need to clear **except** from that patches-own variable (i.e. without using `clear-all` or `clear-patches` in that passage, because such commands would also clear the patches-own variable that you want to keep).

This approach is doable if you are not interested in having **exactly** the same turtle starting on that same patch, but you are happy to have any turtle starting on any of the starting patches.

So it will be something like:

```
globals [
 ; Put here your gobal variables.
]

patches-own [
 slope  ; I only included this to show that you have to manually clear the patches' variables EXCEPT from 'starting-patch?'.
 starting-patch?
]

turtles-own [
  ; Put here your turtles' variables.
]


to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  
  ; Do here what you need to do to prepare the baseline scenario.
  
  create-turtles 20 [
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   set starting-patch? TRUE
  ]
  
  ask patches [
   set slope random 5
   if (starting-patch? = 0) [
     set starting-patch? FALSE
    ] 
  ]
end


to go
  run-model
  
  clear-baseline-scenario
  prepare-future-scenario
  
  run-model
end


to run-model
  ; Put here all the things you need to have to run your model,
  ; including a stop condition (and ticks, if you want them).
end


to clear-baseline-scenario
  clear-globals
  clear-turtles
  reset-ticks
  
  ; Now, you also have to manually clear all your patches' variables that you
  ; want to clear EXCEPT from 'my-start':
  ask patches [
   set slope 0 
  ]
end


to prepare-future-scenario
  ; Do here what you need to do to prepare the future scenario,
  ; and also tell your agents to go to an empty starting patch:
  
  create-turtles 20 [
   move-to one-of patches with [(starting-patch?) AND (not any? turtles-here)]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Matteo. I actually have one scenario per run. I was actually thinking how can I combine both scenario in a single run. Your answer helped a lot. Thank you.